# How to set OnItemClickListener() with implicit ListView use and default adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

Usually I set my ItemClickListener using

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    long x = MyActivity.this.myAdapter.getItemId(position); //to get the clicked item position
            }
        });
```

After setting my ListView etc.

Now I have to work on a code that use the list with default Android list adapter in this way

```
public class ListDefs extends ListActivity {
        private Defs defs;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            defs = Note.defs;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, defs.lines);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }
```

How to set a `OnItemClickListener()` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListActivity has both a [getListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListAdapter%28%29) and [getListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) methods.

In your onCreate, after you call

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);
```

where R.layout.list_activity is your layout file for the activity that has a ListView tagged with the android list id like so (according to the docs)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    ... />
```

you can call

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
    ...
    }
});
```

From the docs

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)